# Unable to assign Resource Key to asp.net Label

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am new to development , as startup, am learning from different videos and tutorials. Right now am facing a strange problem

i have a asp.net label

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Label1TextKey %>" />
```

and i have defined his key in

```
App_GlobalResources >>  Resource.resx >> Label1TextKey
```

but when i build , it is giving

```
Error   1   The resource object with key 'Label1TextKey' was not found.      C:\Documents and Settings\Maya\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebSite1\Default.aspx  14
```

Can and body help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you are using wrongly

correct declaration is

```
<%$ Resources:[filename prefix,]resource-key %>
```

in your case 
File name is `Resource`
and resource-key is `Label1TextKey`

Source
http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/localization/localization.aspx

Answer (score 5):

It should be:

```
Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,Label1TextKey %>"
```

The syntax is like this:

```
<%$ Resources:ClassName,KeyName,DefaultValue %>
```

where `ClassName` is the name of the resource file and `KeyName` is the key inside this file.